# "Unresolved library: keyboard" - Visual Studio Code, Robot Framework project

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework, automation-testing

I installed the keyboard library by "pip install keyboard" in the CMD/terminal, but my VSC still does not read it? It's a robot framework automation testing project

https://prnt.sc/l1o6iEMsKAOA

Comment: Always upload the screenshot within the question instead of providing a link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to load a python library, namely [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) as a RobotFramework library, which is not possible and that's why you get your current error.

To fix your problem you need to create your [own custom library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) that makes use of the `keyboard` python library. You can also search for existing [RobotFramework libraries](https://robotframework.org/#resources) that allows you to do what you need. I'm not sure what you want to do, but be aware that `BuiltIn`, `OperatingSystem`, `Process` libraries might be able to execute keyboard commands.